# How can i cancel/stop a backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In doowrk event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            _stopwatch.Restart();
            DirSearch(@"d:\c-sharp", "*.cs", "Form1");
            _stopwatch.Stop();
        }
```

The problem is that i'm calling DirSearch in dowork event so i can't pass the worker to the DirSearch.

And if i will pass the worker to the DirSearch then i will need to do in the DirSearch :

```
if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
```

But e is not exist in the DirSearch.

```
private void DirSearch(string root, string filesExtension,string textToSearch)
        {
            int numberoffiles = 0;
            int numberofdirs = 0;
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(root, filesExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
            {
                List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();
                int var = File.ReadAllText(filePaths[i]).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;
                if (var == 1)
                {
                    string filename = filePaths[i];
                    numberoffiles ++;
                    prog.Add(new MyProgress { Report1 = filename, Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString() });
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, prog);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                numberofdirs ++;
                label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                label1.Text = numberofdirs.ToString();
                                label1.Visible = true;
                            });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just break out of the for-loop when it's canceled.

Comment: Well then pass it to DirSearch,   There is example of exactly this is the documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: And format to the left.   Why even have a background worker if you are going to report and update every single loop?

Comment: @Paparazzi using async/await as Scott suggesting is better ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a BackgroundWorker you will need to pass `DoWorkEventArgs` and `BackgroundWorker` in to your function.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    _stopwatch.Restart();
    DirSearch(@"d:\c-sharp", "*.cs", "Form1", worker, e);
    _stopwatch.Stop();
}
private void DirSearch(string root, string filesExtension,string textToSearch, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int numberoffiles = 0;
    int numberofdirs = 0;
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(root, filesExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();
        int var = File.ReadAllText(filePaths[i]).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;
        if (var == 1)
        {
            string filename = filePaths[i];
            numberoffiles ++;
            prog.Add(new MyProgress { Report1 = filename, Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString() });
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, prog);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        numberofdirs ++;
        label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        label1.Text = numberofdirs.ToString();
                        label1.Visible = true;
                    });
    }
}
```

Here is a quick reimplmentation using async/await and `Task.Run`

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();

private async Task SearchDirectories()
{
    if (source != null)
    {
        //Cancel the previously running instance.
        source.Cancel();
    }
    source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var foundProgress = new Progress<MyProgress>(/* Some code here*/);
    var totalProgress = new Progress<int>(numberofdirs =>
    {
            label1.Text = numberofdirs.ToString();
            label1.Visible = true;
    });

    try
    {
        _stopwatch.Restart();
        await Task.Run(() => DirSearch(@"d:\c-sharp", "*.cs", "Form1", source.Token, foundProgress, totalProgress), source.Token);
        _stopwatch.Stop();

        //Do any code here you had in BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        //Do any special code here if it was canceled.
    }

}

private void DirSearch(string root, string filesExtension, string textToSearch, CancellationToken token, IProgress<MyProgress> foundProgress, IProgress<int> totalProgress)
{
    int numberoffiles = 0;
    int numberofdirs = 0;
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(root, filesExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        int var = File.ReadAllText(filePaths[i]).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;
        if (var == 1)
        {
            string filename = filePaths[i];
            numberoffiles++;
            var prog = new MyProgress { Report1 = filename, Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString() };
            foundProgress.Report(prog);
        }
        numberofdirs++;
        totalProgress.Report(numberofdirs);
    }
}
```